# Weird content behavior, doesn't fill its parent

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a one page website.
I have a div called .INsobre and its parent wrapper .sobre

The content I have in there are two columns, one floating left and another right but they are not filling up the .INsobre div.

As you can see in this print, the blue outline is the .INsobre div.
[image]

Why is this happening? How can I fix?

my html

```
<div class="sobre">
    <div class="INsobre">
        <div class="sobreLeft">
            <img src="img/sobre/empresa.png">
        </div>
        <div class="sobreRight">
            <h2>SOBRE NÓS</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius ipsum eget augue aliquam pulvinar. Duis cursus vulputate odio ac elementum. In posuere lorem vel erat mollis, eleifend feugiat augue porttitor. Donec eu tristique sem. Nullam tincidunt vel felis quis vehicula. Fusce a sagittis purus, ac pellentesque lectus.
            </p>
            <p>
                Phasellus cursus cursus risus, id malesuada ex varius ut. Mauris volutpat erat purus, sed egestas ex semper porttitor. Vivamus sit amet hendrerit purus, eu interdum mauris. Quisque nec eleifend turpis, vulputate placerat ligula. Suspendisse blandit ipsum in efficitur varius. Aliquam a odio id lorem placerat ultrices eget ac leo. Integer non vulputate lacus. Sed tincidunt vehicula semper. Mauris ac nulla non mauris egestas sollicitudin.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="solicitar_visita"><span>SOLICITE A NOSSA VISITA</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css

```
/* SOBRE NÓS */
.sobre{
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
.INsobre{
    width: 1200px;
    padding: 80px 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sobreLeft{
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.sobreLeft img{
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 6px solid #59B200;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}
.sobreRight{
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 30px 0 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sobreRight h2{
    margin: 0 0 45px 20px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #FF8000;
}
.sobreRight p{
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 19px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left: 3px solid #59B200;
}

.sobreRight .solicitar_visita{
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #59B200;
    color: #59B200;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
       -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
         -o-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
            transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
}
.sobreRight .solicitar_visita:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: #59B200;
}
```

Comment: Use `clear:both`. There are plenty of articles to explain how to clear floats. First 2 on google: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html and https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: As a side-note, *do not* use upper-case letters on class-names. Instead of `.sobre-left`, use `.sobre-left` or `.sobre.left`.

Comment: @sdcr I chose that one because he/she explained why it happened instead of giving a straight forward solution. Also I didn't need to follow any link to know what happened to my divs. I still appreciate everyone who answers of course, but you just gotta pick one...

Comment: @White8Tiger agreed, that is the thing of SO, we all trying to answer questions asap, in order to get more attentions and possibly more reps. The other thing is lots of the questions are duplicated, people are tired to type in everything to explain it. Anyway, I have completed my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30080476/483779) below, and wish you would be able to learn more useful stuff from it, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `overflow:auto` to `.INsobre`:

```
.INsobre{
    width: 1200px;
    padding: 80px 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Floating the children elements allows the parent to collapse as if they didn't exist. Adding the overflow rule restores the behavior that you're after.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

**or:**

```
.clear {
clear:both;
height:0;
margin:0;
font-size: 1px;
line-height: 0;
}
```

[Read More.](https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/)

**Alternative**ly, `display:inline-block`

Comment: Or `overflow:visible;`.

Answer (score 1):

If a parent element contains nothing but floated elements, the height of it would literally collapse to nothing.

The reason that you still see highlighted blue lines have some height is because you have this rule `.INsobre{padding: 80px 10px;}` set, without it it will actually collapse to nothing.

To fix it, there are few ways, such as the famous *[micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)*:

```
.INsobre:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Or, use `overflow:auto` or `overflow:hidden`. Be aware by setting up this it will not work properly if you want to have something that is positioned out of the box in the future. i.e. an element is set to `position:absolute; right:-50px;` inside the container.

```
.INsobre {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Updated Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mcrwe9ym/